# Why "Move" of class to file with same namespace/name.h in AppCode results in empty .h while all class code is moved to .cpp?

Tags: c++, appcode

Wondering around new C++ refactoring tool - [AppCode](http://blog.jetbrains.com/objc/) I had a few simple questions: how to move class to a file with corresponding name (namespace/name.h), how to move a function declared in `.h` to `.cpp`, how to move back?

So I had a sample code we want to move:

[image]

We'll get a `fun.h` with next code:

```
#ifndef __fun_H_
#define __fun_H_

#endif //__fun_H_
```

and fun.cpp with all our class in it (declaration + implementation).

What do I do wrong? how to move class into a new .h file with name corresponding to it in AppCode?

Answer (score 2):

Can't reproduce this problem. If you have the reproducible sample project, please create the issue in the AppCode tracker http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/OC and attach the sample.

Comment: (main point is that I move from `main.cpp`, moving from `.h` file works fine)